# open-loop vs closed loop

Tags: maf

My car sprung a `P0101` pending code recently, which shows up as a `Mass or Volume Air Flow Sensor "A" Circuit Range/Performance` on my BlueDriver OBDII scanner. I started to read this article [SUCCESSFUL MAF SENSOR DIAGNOSIS](https://www.motor.com/magazine-summary/successful-maf-sensor-diagnosis/) by Sam Bell and I couldn't follow this discussion that uses the terms open-loop and closed-loop. What exactly is this referring to and how can I trigger each in my vehicle?

> To function correctly, all of the air entering an engine's combustion
>   chambers must be "seen" by the MAF sensor. This means that any vacuum
>   or air leak downstream of the sensor will result in insufficient fuel
>   metering, causing a lean condition in **open-loop operation** and
>   higher-than-normal fuel trim values in **closed-loop**.

Comment: Open and closed loop are control algorithms usually coded in the ecu - but to solve your problems apply the tests and look at the results, the code and meaning you show suggest a replacement sensor is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The engine runs in "open loop" when first started, before the oxygen sensors come up to operating temperature. It basically means the fuel is being metered with MAP/MAF as the primary input.

Once warmed up, fuel is metered by an active feedback loop with the O2 sensor, known as closed-loop operation.

Answer (score 2):

Open and closed loop are control algorithms usually coded in the ecu - but to solve your problems apply the tests and look at the results, the code and meaning you show suggest a replacement sensor is required.

The trim values can usually be used, if they are editable, to "fine tune" the sensor in the application - perhaps due to parameters such as pipe length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Trim levels generally refer to fuel trims.  St and lt.  Short term and long term.   They are essentially the correction factors introduced following a combustion cycle reading. At the o2 sensor.  You have air. fuel. spark. and the o2's detect the remaining fuel/oxygen mixture.  This generates a  correction; short term and long term.   If your able to log those values huge corrections like over 5% ST is ideal.  And maybe up TO 20% long term.   All this is in a traditional internal combustion engine.   Not turbo\ supercharged ,nitrous or hybrid.  Though principles are standards.  It really matters what vehicle we are talking about. Hope that helps a bit.